# AJAX BitMovin - GET request is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, composer-php

I've tried searching for a solution but I have an issue trying to determine what to search. I'm trying to use AJAX for a PHP Get request and it seems to be submitting (like leaving the page).

I'm using the BitMovin library which seems to be the issue. The code works for starting a livestream however the AJAX doesn't. When I comment out the BitMovin code it, the AJAX works.

What happens when running the request with BitMovin code uncommented, it opens this page (It is suppose to complete the request in background):

```
{ "data": { "success" : true, "message" : "Success!" } }
```

The script:

```
<?php
use bitcodin\AwsRegion;
use bitcodin\Bitcodin;
use bitcodin\VideoStreamConfig;
use bitcodin\AudioStreamConfig;
use bitcodin\Job;
use bitcodin\JobConfig;
use bitcodin\Input;
use bitcodin\S3InputConfig;
use bitcodin\EncodingProfile;
use bitcodin\EncodingProfileConfig;
use bitcodin\ManifestTypes;
use bitcodin\Output;
use bitcodin\S3OutputConfig;

use bitcodin\GcsOutputConfig;
use bitcodin\HttpInputConfig;
use bitcodin\LiveStream;

require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
//more code for my site
if (!empty($errors)) {
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
}else{
    Bitcodin::setApiToken('---my-key-removed-for-post---');
    $encodingProfileConfig = new EncodingProfileConfig();
    $encodingProfileConfig->name = 'Encoding Name';

    $low = new VideoStreamConfig();
    $low->bitrate = 1000000;
    $low->height = 480;
    $low->width = 854;
    $encodingProfileConfig->videoStreamConfigs[] = $low;

    $audio = new AudioStreamConfig();
    $audio->bitrate = 128000;
    $encodingProfileConfig->audioStreamConfigs[] = $audio;

    $encodingProfile = EncodingProfile::create($encodingProfileConfig);

    $outputConfig = new S3OutputConfig();
    $outputConfig->name         = "OutputName";
    $outputConfig->accessKey    = "--removed-for-post---";
    $outputConfig->secretKey    = "--removed-for-post---";
    $outputConfig->bucket       = "bucketName";
    $outputConfig->region       = AwsRegion::US_WEST_2;
    $outputConfig->prefix       = 'folder/test';
    $outputConfig->makePublic   = false;
    $output = Output::create($outputConfig);

    $liveInstance = LiveStream::create('StreamName', 'StreamKey', $encodingProfile, $output, 0);

    while($liveInstance->status != $liveInstance::STATUS_RUNNING)
    {
        sleep(2);
        $liveInstance->update();
        if($liveInstance->status == $liveInstance::STATUS_ERROR)
        {
            $errors['bitmovin'] = 'Error with bitmovin';
            $data['errors']  = $errors;
            //throw new \Exception("Error occurred during Live stream creation");
        }
    }

    $rtmpUrl = "";
    $rtmpUrl = $liveInstance->rtmpPushUrl;

    $streamInstanceId = $liveInstance->id;

    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Success!';
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

This is the AJAX code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#start").click(function(event){
        var formData = {};
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'GET',
            url         : './foobar.php',
            data        : formData, 
            dataType    : 'json',
            encode      : true
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);  
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><a href="#" id="start">Start</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

So I know it's the BitMovin code, why is it opening the code in a new page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: event.preventDefault(); is not firing. Don't forget to add it into your args
change this `$("#start").click(function(){` 
to this `$("#start").click(function(event){`

Comment: @Conceptz Yes sorry that is there. Just copy and pasted it wrong

Answer (score 1):

as already clarified in our support conversation, the issue doesn't seem to be related to the [bitcodin-php API Client](https://github.com/bitmovin/bitcodin-php).

FYI: It isn't mandatory to create a new encoding profile with every livestream. You can use an existing one, with `EncodingProfile::get(<yourEncodingProfileId>)`. More informations about our API Clients can be found at https://bitmovin.com/encoding-documentation/encoding-api/

Best,
Gernot